# Concatenate data of different objects in one list

Tags: query, list

I want to create an overview of a list which contains content from different objects. I will try to add in this list the files, tasks, events, emails and notes. If I query for each object a list, how can I concatenate all these lists into one list. Is that possible because of different object and structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The generic `sObject` can hold any type of database record, such as:

```
sObject[] results = new sObject[0];
results.addAll([SELECT Title FROM ContentDocument]);
results.addAll([SELECT Subject FROM Task]);
results.addAll([SELECT Subject FROM Event]);
results.addAll([SELECT Subject From EmailMessage]);
results.addAll([SELECT Title FROM Note]);
```

If you decide you want to use a Data Transfer Object (DTO) model in your code, you can also decide to use a parent DTO object type, or even just `Object`, which is the parent of all object types.

Comment: I am not sure I understand difference between DTO and a wrapper class. Can you please enlighten me. For example in author scenario I am thinking wrapper class would also suffice scenario.

Comment: @elijah A DTO (Data Transfer Object) is a subset of a wrapper. In other words, all DTO are wrappers, but not all wrappers are DTO, much like how all dogs are animals, but not all animals are dogs. You are correct that a wrapper class would be employed, it's just that a DTO usually has minimal functionality, designed only to transfer data between client and server, while a full wrapper class often has methods to aid manipulating the data somehow.

Comment: Sorry, one more questen. Can you tell me how can I display the results at a visualforce page?

Comment: @peXeq You may want to ask a separate question for that. We would need much more detail than a comment is going to be able to provide.